# Change a drive letter from Command Prompt or batch script in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, command-line, batch

I have an external hard drive that I connect often to my computer. At some point it was assigned letter G: and based on that my other software works.

Nowadays, suddenly it gets letter F:

Is there any way I can use a batch script to change the letter from F: to G:. I don't mind running the batch script manually?

If so, what is the code I should use and will it need administrative permissions?

Comment: See `diskpart` and yes you need admin. In theory it should have remembered the drive letter, consider changing it manually on disk management first.

Comment: @Bob: It could be that it only remembers drive letters after they have been assigned manually at least once.

Comment: Thanks! I have changed it a couple of times manually, but everytime it goes back to the old one.

Comment: I have noticed that it was remembered when I had one device using a drive letter. When I started using multiple devices with the same drive letter, they get forgot, I have not verified the hypothesis, but I guess Windows 10 remembers the last device assigned to a drive letter.

Answer (score 3):

There are several methods:

- `mountvol` – use it once to delete an existing letter, then again to assign a new one;
- `diskpart` – interactive;
- `diskmgmt.msc` aka Disk Management – a graphical tool.

Whichever you choose, assigning once should be enough, the assignment will be remembered afterwards.