# Linux boot fails after booting Windows: root partition in use. How to resolve?

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, linux-mint, fsck

I try to setup a Linux Mint 19 and Windows 10 dual-boot.
(both in BIOS mode)

Windows is installed on /dev/sdc, Linux is installed to /dev/sdb
Besides Linux there is a NTFS partition on /dev/sdb too. 
See the fdisk -l output:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000397852160 bytes, 3907027055 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe70e336d

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb2          2002942 3907024064 3905021123   1.8T  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       1034216568 3907024064 2872807497   1.3T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb6  *     517107712 1034215423  517107712 246.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb7        515155968  517105663    1949696   952M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb8          2002944  515153919  513150976 244.7G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Now, while setting up Linux Mint after install, everything runs fine. I can reboot without an issue. 
But as soon as I boot into Windows, it **blocks /dev/sdb completely** and I am no longer able to boot into Linux. 
The boot ends with a **kernel panic**, dropping me to **BusyBox**.

When checking the drive after booting a USB thumb drive, 
fsck /dev/sdb says:

```
root@mint:~# fsck /dev/sdb
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sdb is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

Please note: /dev/sdb is NOT mounted at this point.

Oh and "fastboot" is turned off in Windows. It happens after a reboot as well as after a shutdown. Somehow Windows keeps the drive busy, even after a reboot. :-/

Any ideas on how to prevent this?

**UPDATE**

So I used the wrong fsck command. I did it again with the correct command and get the following:

```
root@mint:~# fsck /dev/sdb1

fsck from util-linux 2.31.1 e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018) 
ext2fs_open2: Superblock checksum does not match superblock 
fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks... 
/dev/sdb1 was not cleanly unmounted, check forced. 
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
```

After that I get like a thousand invalid blocks, which can all be corrected by fsck. After this, I can boot again into Linux. But only as long as I don't boot into Windows. As soon as I do that, everything is broken again.

I rearranged the partitions on that HDD as well, without success.

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000397852160 bytes, 3907027055 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe70e336d

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          2048  515104767  515102720 245.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2        515106814 3907024064 3391917251   1.6T  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       1034216568 3907024064 2872807497   1.3T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb6        515106816 1032214527  517107712 246.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb7       1032216576 1034215423    1998848   976M 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Oh and Smarty says that the HDD is healthy and just fine. 
There must be a reason why Windows in messing with the partition table in that way...

Comment: You run `fsck /dev/sdb` as if a filesystem existed on `/dev/sdb`. But it shouldn't be there; should it? `sdb` holds partitions, not a filesystem. I get `/dev/sdb is in use` and my `sdb` also holds partitions. However this doesn't explain why kernel panic occurs. Is the disk healthy? How is Linux boot organized? Is it with GRUB? Where is `/boot`? Where is GRUB? From BusyBox, can you get to any relevant logs?

Comment: You are right... `fsck /dev/sdb` was the wrong command.
I did a `fsck /dev/sdb1` and was flooded with errors.
`fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Superblock checksum does not match superblock
fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
/dev/sdb1 was not cleanly unmounted, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes`
The errors get corrected and I can boot normally again after that, but it fails again after booting Windows. Seems as Windows is shredding the partition table or so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so apparently this has something to do with ex2fsd, which is a Windows tool to access ext2,3,4 formatted HDDs. It cannot cope with `64bit` and the `metadata_csum feature`.

This helped me:
[windows-10-corrupting-the-ext4-superblock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/849872/how-can-i-prevent-windows-10-from-corrupting-the-ext4-superblock-every-time)

If you ran into the same issue:

1. boot into a live linux (eg Ubuntu 16.04 or later)
2. correct the ext4 superblock with `sudo fsck /dev/sdXX` (XX is the number of the partition).
3. Remove `64bit` and `metadata_csum` with `sudo tune2fs -O ^metadata_csum,^64bit /dev/sdXX`

That should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could comment out the mounting of /dev/sdb5 from /etc/fstab.  Once you've done that it shouldn't throw a kernel panic because the partition that is the issue won't try to boot.  I've found [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/704870/mount-and-dismount-hard-drive-through-a-script-software) which should be helpful to unmount the particular drive before rebooting or shutdown in Windows 10.  You could just write a new shutdown script or depending on which version of Windows 10 you could set the script to run at shutdown using [GPO](https://lifehacker.com/use-group-policy-editor-to-run-scripts-when-shutting-do-980849001) or the [registry](https://serverfault.com/questions/377387/how-to-add-a-shutdown-script-not-by-using-gpedit-msc-or-active-directory).

Comment: please see edit above in main post...